# Align Format-Table output in powershell after converting to string

Tags: powershell, alignment, output

After converting this table to a string, the columns are no longer aligned correctly. The data in the columns are, but the 3 columns themselves are not. Ideally I would want them aligned to the left. Is there any way to fix this? The reason I converted to a string is to eliminate unneeded space.

```
  (Get-EventLog system -computername $computernamehere -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 `
        | Format-Table `
            @{Name="Event ID";Expression = { $_.EventID }; Alignment="left" },
            @{Name="TimeWritten";Expression = { $_.TimeWritten }; Alignment="left" },
            @{Name="Machine Name";Expression = { $_.MachineName }; Alignment="left" } `
        | Out-String).Trim()
```

Comment: Why do you need to eliminate unneeded spaces? Is your end goal to have the output in a file?

Comment: I output the data on screen with other data, and everything is separated 1 line apart. This outputs with extra lines above and below, so I had to remove them by converting to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on my own. Just needed -Autosize. If anyone else has a better way, please let me know.

```
(Get-EventLog system -computername $computernamehere -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 `
    | Format-Table -Autosize `
        @{Name="Event ID";Expression = { $_.EventID }; Alignment="left" },
        @{Name="TimeWritten";Expression = { $_.TimeWritten }; Alignment="left" },
        @{Name="Machine Name";Expression = { $_.MachineName }; Alignment="left" } `
    | Out-String).Trim()
```